# Delphi 7 Personal, MySQL using libmysql.dll + UTF8

Tags: mysql, delphi, unicode, utf-8, libmysql

I'm using Delphi 7 Personal. To access MySQL database I'm using libmysql.dll + very simple wrapper, which is good enough for me. Except one thing ... it doesn't seem to handle Utf8... is that possible somehow to pass Utf8 strings from libmysql to Delphi? Please keep in mind I'm not using commercial delphi, this means no ADO / dbExpress... ;)

Thanks in advance,
m.

Comment: Since UTF8 basically can be passed around as strings, have you tried them as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally what I did is querying "SET NAMES 'cp1250'", replacing the character set depending on the system default charset...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass and receive Base64 data, see here the functions source: http://wi-fizzle.com/downloads/base64.sql

Comment: unfortunately, the app I'm developing is kind of a simple MySQL manager, therefore it cannot depend on non-standard server-side functionality. Nor can it add own functions ...